# Compiling with 64-bit MinGW on Code::Blocks

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I'm trying to set up my Code::Blocks installation to work with the SDL2 graphics API.  As the documentation suggests, once I had everything installed and specified correctly, I tried the 
`SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)` test, as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nSDL2 could not be initialized! Code: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I got the following errors:

```
...in function 'SDL_Main':
undefined reference to `SDL_Init`
undefined reference to `SDL_GetError`
undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
```

I looked these errors up and they seem to be due to CodeBlocks using a 32-bit compiler, but I'm using the 64-bit SDL2 library. Which makes sense, as my linked options are:

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

So, I used MinGW's `WinBuilds` tool to download the 64-bit MinGW fork, which gave me a massive amount of files in a new `/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/...` folder. Then I went to CodeBlocks' `Settings -> Compiler -> Toolchain Executables` and pointed the respective compiler executables at the exe's in `bin`. My first thought was to then change `-lmingw32` to `-lmingw64`, but this doesn't work. I get the error:

```
cannot find -lmingw64
```

At this point I'm not sure what I've done correctly, incorrectly, what is broken/working etc. and would really appreciate any help possible.

It may also be worth noting that I extracted the 64-bit compiler to `C:\MinGW` and pointed CodeBlocks at `C:\MinGW\bin` as the compiler installation directory. When I click `Auto-Detect`, it seems happy enough and states it has automatically found the GCC compiler in that location. Therefore, it must be my `-lmingw64` flag that is wrong, or something else I have specified.

Edit: The 64-bit compiler was set up and detected correctly but continued to produce errors relating to `SDL` functions:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Initialization_Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `SDL_main':|
C:\C\SDL_C_Graphics\Init_Test\Initialization_Test\main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `_SDL_Init'|
C:\C\SDL_C_Graphics\Init_Test\Initialization_Test\main.cpp|10|undefined reference to `_SDL_GetError'|
C:\C\SDL_C_Graphics\Init_Test\Initialization_Test\main.cpp|10|undefined reference to `_printf'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `__tcf_0':|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream|74|undefined reference to `__ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream|74|undefined reference to `__ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream|74|undefined reference to `_atexit'|
C:\SDL_Dev\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o)||In function `main_getcmdline':|
\Users\valve\release\SDL\SDL2-2.0.12-source\foo-x64\..\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c|71|undefined reference to `SDL_main'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Command CodeBlocks may be executing for compilation, in separate log window:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SDL_Dev\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\SDL_Dev\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\SDL_Dev\SDL_Img\SDL2_image-2.0.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\SDL_Dev\SDL_Mixer\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -L"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\lib" -o bin\Debug\Initialization_Test.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -ldxguid
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `obj\Debug\main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error output? Every detail may be important.

Comment: *"they seem to be due to CodeBlocks using a 32-bit compiler, but I'm using the 64-bit SDL2 library"* Yes, that's probably it. *"My first thought was to then change  -lmingw32 to -lmingw64, but this doesn't work."* You don't need to change anything, use `-lmingw32`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the response. I changed back to `-lmingw32`, and while it seems to find the compiler now, I'm just back to the original `undefined reference` errors to the `SDL` functions. There must be something else that I'm missing.

Comment: @Rowan Please post the exact error messages. Does it still complain about `WinMain@16` or not?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, there is no error for WinMain@16 now. I'll edit the original post and add the full output the end now.

Comment: Please also show the command Code::Blocks is executing. I really hope it prints it right before the error output happens.

Comment: @rubenvb Thanks for the comment. I have included this (hopefully) in another edit.
It seems to mention "incompatible architecture with i386". I'm sure this is 32-bit. The filepath for the compiler also seems to be wrong (it has returned to the `Program Files` folder where it initially extracted to).
There are a few things here I definietely need to look at myself.

Comment: Looks like a broken compiler installation to me. I suggest uninstalling MinGW (and keeping MinGW-w64). Also, you have too many libraries in the linker flags: `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -ldxguid`. You only need the first three.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, that sounds like a good idea. 
Also r.e. the linker flags, I haven't added those manually and I can't find them anywhere. When I go to `Settings -> Compiler -> Linker Settings` in the box `Other linker options` there are only the first three, as specified: 
`-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`
How did the others get there?

Comment: @Rowan Check global compiler settings (somewhere in CB settings), and project-wide compiler settings. (When in build settings window, there should be a tree on the left side, displaying the project name and all build targets (release, debug, etc). If you click on a target name, it shows settings for that target, and if you click on the project name, it shows project-wide settings.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks again. I knew I had changed both the project and global compiler settings individually, but it looks like I was at least consistent as the linker flags for both were the same.

I've had a tinker and everything seems to be working fine now. I've changed the syntax from C to C++ (including adding `<iostream>` and removing the C headers, of course) and that now works, too. I'm not 100% sure what I changed which fixed the issue, but at least I can start learning now!
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** Your last edit shows the most important bit of the output (it's incidentally also the first part of the output):

```
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `obj\Debug\main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

This is the linker telling you you are mixing 32 and 64-bit binaries.
It seems you compiled your source file `main.cpp` into a 32-bit binary object `obj\Debug\main.o`. **You'll need to provide the commands 
leading to the creation of that file.**

---

Some general remarks:

1. The last symbol you're missing, `WinMain@16` is a Windows-specific entry point that you "request" by compiling/linking with `-mwindows` and is typical/necessary for a native Win32 GUI application. It also seems linking `SDL2main` "causes" this.
2. The "32"s you see in various system libraries and compiler prefixes reflects the API you're targeting, which is called "Win32", even on 64-bit Windows.

On to the error information you posted:

The undefined references to C++ symbols imply you are linking with `gcc` but instead should be linking with `g++` which automagically links in the C++ bits you need. These missing symbols are needed because you included `<iostream>` which causes some global initialization to happen.

I cannot reproduce your linker error with MSYS2's build of SDL2. Your test code gives me the following output:

```
g++ main.cpp -o sdl_test -lSDL2main -lSDL2
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
D:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For which I can refer back to my point 1 above. But that is not your issue as it's first complaining about the SDL symbols.

Comment: `undefined reference to WinMain@16` is caused by `#define main SDL_main` in `SDL.h`. `SDL2_main` provides `WinMain@16`, so linking it correctly should fix this error.

Comment: Thanks @rubenvb. When you create a new `SDL` project in CodeBlocks, it includes that header automatically. I removed it, and the build now succeeds!
I am hoping to use C rather than C++, but I have `g++` pointed to correctly under `Toolchain executables` so I'm still not sure why it isn't able to link correctly.

Comment: @Rowan Pro tip: don't use CB project templates. Create an empty project and configure it from scratch.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've seen the trick used by Qt as well (and I've used it as well) but I still get the linker error with MSYS2's packages which seems to imply either the MSYS2 packages are broken somehow (rather unlikely) or some other piece of the puzzle is missing.

Comment: @rubenvb MSYS2 packages work on my end. I can compile `#include <SDL2/SDL.h> int main(int, char**) {SDL_Init(0);}` with `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` (using a 64-bit GCC).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It was a missing `-lmingw32`. Never had to link that manually myself before. I'm spoiled by CMake I guess.